# How can I solve "import <some java path> can not be resolved"?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

How can I resolve

> import some_path/some_library can not be resolved

?

Comment: It depends on your project setup, some classes may be in another project, some other copied to a lib folder, some others are using a dependency manager like maven. So.. can you show your project setup? maybe a screenshot works. Summary, Eclipse cannot find some_path/some_library in the default library references.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

> 1. Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
> 2. Remove the JRE System Library
> 3. Add it back; Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library. The default worked for me.

**Solution 2**

> 1. Go to Project
> 2. Select Clean then click on clean all projects and Press ok

**Solution 3**

> Check the JRE version in the build Path is it 1.5 or 1.6. Try with
>   different version

**Solution 4**

> 1. Right Click on Project
> 2. Click on *Plug-in Tools*
> 3. Click on *Update ClassPath*

One of them is likely to work. Hope it helps.